# How many sugyot are marked in the 1835 Vilna Printing of the Talmud Bavli?

Tags: number, talmud-bavli

How many sugyot are marked in the 1835 Vilna printing of the Talmud Bavli?

I am defining a sugya by a section divided between "two dots" ( : ) or between the words of mishna and "two dots".

I am curious to compare this number to other possible countings of Halachot.

I imagine if one has access to the Bar Ilan research tools, it will aid in this answer.

Comment: This is one of a group of similar questions: [_mitzvos_](http://yodeya.com/q/34253), [_Mishna_](http://yodeya.com/q/34224), [_Y'rushalmi_](http://yodeya.com/q/34254), [_Bavli_](http://yodeya.com/q/34252), [_Mishne Tora_](http://yodeya.com/q/34248), [_Shulchan Aruch_](http://yodeya.com/q/34249), [_Mishna B'rura_](http://yodeya.com/q/34251),  [_Yalkut Yosef_](http://yodeya.com/q/34250)

Comment: Wow, so many down votes... without any explanation.  This community rocks!

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146

Comment: It just doesn't look like an interesting question IMHO

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that my interests don't interest you!  It's always nice to have reminders, of why one made previous choices...  If I lied and said that I wanted to know how to break up my learning by this method, would you then find it interesting?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The purpose of a downvote is to mark something as not useful. If somebody else wants to know the answer to this question, do you think that this question would be the least usefull to find the answer?

Comment: Do you know bar ilan responsa project uses the same breakup as the 1835 vilna edition?

Comment: @DoubleAA it says,  Vilna edition, Punctuation using Machon Tevel edition,  Bnei Brak. 1961 as well as the Steinsaltz edition. And as far as I can tell, Steinsaltz has the two dots as well.